# %Clipboard% never changes

Tags: autohotkey

I want to show the *current* (=changing) item of the Windows clipboard in a text field where I can do basic text editing. I made it work like so:

```
<^>!x:: ; AltGr + x
    Gui +Resize ; +MinSize300x200
    Gui, Add, Edit, , %Clipboard% ; flexibe size (fits content)
    Gui, Show ;
    Return
```

However, the problem is that no matter how many items I copy, `%Clipboard%` always only holds the very first clipboard item which I copied upon loading the above script. It never changes.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<^>!x:: ; AltGr + x
    Gui, destroy 
    Gui +Resize ; +MinSize300x200
    Gui, Add, Edit, , %Clipboard% ; flexibe size (fits content)
    Gui, Show
Return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Gui.htm#Destroy

If you want to keep the last Gui:

```
<^>!x:: ; AltGr + x
    Gui, New    
    Gui +Resize ; +MinSize300x200
    Gui, Add, Edit, , %Clipboard% ; flexibe size (fits content)
    Gui, Show
Return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Gui.htm#New

Comment: Wow, that was quick! If you are so good at ahk and if you still want to, could you also position the GUI at the mouse cursor (in a multi-monitor set-up) and make the GUI's TEXT field variable in size (by dragging the window's corner)? And MAYBE have it closed by {Esc}? Only if you want to, of course, but then I'd upvote your answer, too :-)

Comment: I'd make a new question of it to give other users the opportunity to answer, in case someone else has a better answer.