# Paste into Notepad

Tags: autohotkey

I just want to paste the current clipboard content into a new Notepad-window, but the following doesn't work:

```
#t::
    Run "notepad.exe"
    WinWaitActive, Untitled - Notepad
    WinActivate, Untitled - Notepad ; to bring the window to the front ?
    ControlSend, Edit1, ^v, ahk_class Notepad
    return
```

Also...

```
ControlSetText, RichEditD2DPT1, New Text Here
```

...only works (writes *New Text Here* into Notepad) after I click into Notepad's text field myself manually.

How can I write the current clipboard item automatically into a new Notepad window via AHK, best via `Ctrl+V`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Run notepad,,, PID ; runs notepad storing its unique Process ID (PID)
WinWait, ahk_pid %PID% 
WinActivate, ahk_pid %PID% 
WinWaitActive, ahk_pid %PID% 
SendInput, ^v
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Run.htm#Parameters

Comment: That works, perfect, thanks! Would you mind looking at my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75336844/ahk-clipboard-never-changes

Comment: I made an answer there.